# Ruby SyntaxError on stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I got Ruby project, and I want to put it in docker. Unfortunately, I have an issue that I cannot solve. Maybe one of you has an idea how to fix or check what is the problem.

I create a docker image based on ruby:2.7.5.
It install all packages and runs. When I try to open home page, I got the below console error:

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error (...)
> ActionView::Template::Error (SyntaxtError: Invalid or unexpected token):

It does not display any more detailed info, but I narrow down the problem to the line `= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media => 'all'` 
When I remove that line, the home page loads correctly. I tried to edit the application.css file but no luck. Empty file, file with single css rule, nothing changes the error.

Ruby version 2.7.5
Rails: 5.2.6

Comment: I don't expect this error has got anything to do with `docker`, and nor is it a problem with the line `stylesheet_link_tag ...`. I expect it's something to do with the file it's loading. Maybe you're not running webpack, and so the changes to `application.css` aren't actually being picked up?

Comment: @TomLord how I can verify that webpack is fine and run?

 css as far I know are served on the fly. the rails server run without any warnings.
I added as much as possible context to my issue, but you are correct, that root cause may be somwhere else.
EDIT: in project is used ```sprockets```

Comment: Can you look in config/environments/development.rb (or whichever environment you're running) and grep for a line reading config.assets.compile. The one line of code you've included looks fine, but just in case, maybe you want to post a bit more code before and after, as well as text from the actual error page. You probably didn't miss anything, but it doesn't hurt to be sure.

Comment: I have bit more context. When I try precompile assets on demand `bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace` I got the same error, but also a stack trace. So it looks like the issue have root cause is package exec.js `ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` `/gems/ruby/2.7.0/gems/execjs-2.8.1/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in 'exec'` I have nodejs v12.22.2, I have package therubyracer. Not sure what else I should check @MarsAtomic any idea?

Comment: This is interesting. You're working with a configuration that I haven't used before, so I'm definitely out of my depth. However... node should be supplying you with a JS V8 engine already, making therubyracer redundant. Remove therubyracer from your gem file and see if things improve.

Comment: Make sure that the application.css file is correctly formatted and does not contain any syntax errors. You can try commenting out all the contents of the file and seeing if the error still occurs. If it does, then the problem is likely not related to the file itself.

Comment: I probably found the root cause. And as I suspect this is because all time solution was developed on MacOS, and now, I check out it on Windows and copy it to Unix. The line endings. As I debug, probably one of the packages (https://github.com/dnagir/ruby-haml-js/blob/master/lib/ruby-haml-js/template.rb#L40) does not escape \r character. And then I have runtime syntax error.